# jQuery find and get html

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to grab the entire html of `.spec` including the `<ul class="spec"></ul>` but using the below code it grabs only the children of `.spec`

**HTML**

```
<div class="single-vacancy">
    <p class="title"><strong>This title</strong></p>
    <span class="read-more">View Vacancy</span>
    <ul class="spec">
        <li>List</li>
        <li>List</li>
        <li>List</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.read-more').click(function() {
    var role = $(this).next('.spec').html();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or the jquery way:

```
var role = $(this).next('.spec').prop('outerHTML');
```

Using `html()` returns only the content HTML (innerHTML) not the outer HTML.

Comment: @PraveenJeganathan updated answer with little explication, thx!

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
$('.read-more').click(function(){
var x = $(this).next('.spec').get(0).outerHTML;
});
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KFutJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can also use, `$('.spec').clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();`

http://jsfiddle.net/A64mJ/

so as shown in your example it would become as,

```
$('.read-more').click(function(){
var role = $(this).next('.spec').clone().wrap('<div/>').parent().html();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UT5Ug/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.read-more').click(function(){
    var role = $("<div>").html($(this).next('.spec')).html();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this implementation

https://github.com/dilvie/jQuery.outerHTML